# Computer keep telling me that the printer exist

Tags: windows-10

I have to run different test on a kyocera printer, that include reinstalling the printer multiple time on my computer to run different test.

However, for some reason even after removing the printer from my computer when I try reinstalling it, the computer keep telling me that a port already has the same name.

What I'm missing here ? what is the solution to correct that ?

I'm running on the lastest windows 10 version, the printer is online and multiple user can used it . I have no problem pinging the printer and accessing is web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well known issue that has been present in Windows for decades.

The printer installation in Windows consists of 2 components:

1. the actual driver
2. The port-definition that specifies how the communication with the printer is done (E.g. LPT, several USB variants, several forms of network-connection.)

When you de-install the printer the driver gets removed, but the port remains. And printer-driver installers are usually pretty stupid and don't realize on the next installation that they can re-use the already existing port-definition. They simply insist on creating a new one which then fails because the port with identical name already exists.

How to remove a port:
(I can't give you detailed steps because I'm on a Mac and don't have a Windows system handy at the moment.)
Pick a random installed printer and go to the advanced printer properties (the old control--panel style panel version) and look at the PORTS tab.
You will see all ports known to the system and 1 has a checkmark indicating it is the port used by the printer you are looking at. The others can be deleted from that same panel.

Please note you can only delete ports that are "removable", like USB and network ports. Ports that relate to build-in hardware (like LPT ports) are a given and can't be removed, but that shouldn't make a difference in your case.

Comment: Oh my I never knew that, this is stupid but thank for the solution.